# Visual Studio 2022 clipboard - intermittently missing columns of text when copying

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Ever since upgrading to Visual Studio 2022 (currently 17.4.3, Windows 10 within a Parallels VM), I've had annoyingly intermittent issues copying to the system clipboard. It's best illustrated with this example:

[image]
Steps taken above:

1. Highlight a small bit of code with the mouse
2. Copy to the clipboard (done via the menus for clarity in the example above, but more usually by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>)
3. Paste the text back into the editor, only to discover that some of the text is missing (usually one or more "left columns" of text). The code is therefore invariably broken.
4. Confirm by pasting the text into Notepad that the text wasn't there in the first place (so it's a `Copy` problem, not a `Paste` problem)

Has anyone seen this before, and knows how to fix it? It doesn't happen every time, or for every block of code.

Comment: Might not be a copy problem either... could be a selection problem. Also, try disabling all extensions, if you have any, and trying again to see if an extension may be at fault.

Comment: Does the same happen if you start the copy on line 1, at the first character, instead of the column which holds the method declaration? I tried a similar on VS2022 and did not experience the issue.

Comment: If you start Visual Studio in 'Safe mode' (i.e. `devenv /safemode`), which disables extensions, does the issue occur? And, just to confirm, you are not doing a column select with the alt key, correct?

Comment: No, just a regular drag-the-mouse copy. Disabling any/all extensions (either manually or via safe mode) doesn't seem to help either. However, @ΩmegaMan 's suggestion DOES work; selecting from the first column does copy all subsequent text. I'll just need to get into the habit of copying the "white space" at the start rather than the first character, at least until whatever's causing this is fixed ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the copy is attempting to do a vertical aligned copy and chopping off the text which falls before the starting point of the copy location for each subsequent lines.

Start the copy rubber-banding at column 0 of the first line and drag to the end location instead.

---

To be clear a vertical copy is done by holding down the <kbd>alt</kbd> key when setting up the region to copy. This is not such a copy.

Comment: Nice. I suspected something like this, but I use Windows so couldn't confirm. It wasn't obvious because the selection window didn't look like "rectangular select" in the GIF like we're used to seeing on Windows. Stranger, the `d` and `t` seem like they should fall outside as they are in a column prior.

Comment: As an aside VS will in some situations show extra text, intellisense information. that visually changes what is actually seen. Such as putting parameter types/names, but then taking them away when one types. Visually you think it's one thing, but it's actually the other. This may be similar.(?)